Advanced Custom Fields in WP_Query: Href Returning Empty
I'm still learning the ropes of PHP so please bear with me!
So basically I have an ACF URL field "author_link" that I want to generate on a "table of contents" page in a list format along with another ACF text field "author_name" .
The author name is displaying fine in the list (when I put get_field directly in the echo), but I cannot seem to get the author link to display in the "href".
Both the author name and author link fields are populated in the posts and are in the same field group in ACF. I also confirmed that the field names are correct and do have values entered.
Here is my code:
<div class="block wrapper">
<h2><span>Contributing Authors</span></h2>
    
<ul>
    <?php 
    $author_name = get_field ('author_name') ;
    $author_link = get_field( 'author_link' );
    $args = array (
    'post_type' => 'post', // your post type
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // grab all the posts
    'meta_key' => 'author_name', 
    'meta_compare' => 'EXISTS', // make sure the post have this acf value
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    );
    
$query = new WP_Query($args);
    
while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="' . $author_link . '">';
    echo get_field ('author_name') ;
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';

endwhile;
    

wp_reset_query();

    
    ?>
    
    </ul>   

</div>

Additionally, I would like the list results to sort in ASC alphabetical order by the last name of the author. Is there any way I can incorporate usort into this code?
Your help is much appreciated!

wp_reset_query is intended for cleaning up after a query_posts call which you haven't done here, did you mean to call wp_reset_postdata? Fetching posts via their post meta/field values is expensive so make sure to cache the result or you'll face performance issues. Also take a look at the WP_Query docs on developer.wordpress.org in the code reference section, the meta_query and the order/orderby fields documentation will contain the answers you're looking for. I'd also be very careful with 'posts_per_page' => -1, don't set it to unlimited unless your server has infinite CPU/RAM

@TomJNowell Hello, thank you, it does seem like wp_reset_postdata should be the correct way! However, my main issues are getting the links to display and then sorting the author names in alphabetical order by last name. Order/orderby works to sort the names by first name only. So I'm having trouble figuring out how to sort it by last name. The first and last names are input in the same ACF text field as (first, last name). It is an ACF field and not the author of the WordPress post. A staff member will be posting these on behalf of the actual authors of the literature.

It seems I got the links to work, however, I had to use get_field directly in the echo again, just like for the author name. I do not know why it does not work with the $author_link variable that was defined. So if anyone can tell me why, it would really educate me! However, I still need to sort it alphabetically by last name.

MySQL just sees a string of text, it has no concept of first/last names so you can't use WP_Query to sort by last name with author_name unless it's stored as "Lastname Firstname". usort would have a similar problem. $author_link is assigned a value before the loop then never updated again, unlike the author name which has a get_field call inside the loop. You might want to pre-calculate or store the last name separately so you can use it for ordering on render using ACF hooks. Remember for the most part get_field is a more complicated version of get_post_meta
